# Chrome crash on Mavericks, wipes out login info

Tags: google-chrome, osx-mavericks

I've been having this issue quite frequently.  I'll be using Chrome (Version 31.0.1650.63) on Mavericks (10.9.1) on my MacbookPro with NO external monitors, and it randomly hangs.  The only workaround is to switch off the machine and restart it.  On restarting, Chrome has lost all its user login information and I need to login again to each site.

Anybody else noticing this?  Any workarounds or solutions.

p.s. Another post said upgrading to 10.9.1 resolved the issue, but not for me.

Comment: I had this on Mountain Lion recently as well (though infrequent and only with external monitors attached).  Just to add another search avenue for you if no answers come about.

Comment: I don't have external monitors attached.  I've also added that point in the main post now since that seems to be a separate issue.